# how to display json response on div

Tags: json, laravel

Hi i am trying to show json response error on div html but unfortuntly it's not showing please help me how to show this ? thanks.

**json response**

```
{"error":"Email is already taken"}
```

**html view**

```
<div class="wallmasterField">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" name="email" value="{{ old('email')}}" id="email"required>
            <div id="response"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**axois script**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#prospects_form").submit(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          let url = "{{route('home.store')}}";
          var name = $("#name").val();
          var email = $("#email").val();

          axios
              .post(url, {
                  name: name,
                  email: email,
              })
              .then((res) => {
                  console.log(res);

              })
              .catch(function (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  $("#response").text(err);

              });
      });
  });
</script>
```

please check controller i am returning json response 422 i think i will use for error message

**controller**

```
       public function store(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->email) {
            $subscribes = Subscribe::where('email', $request->email)->exists();
            if ($subscribes) {
                $response['error'] = 'Email is already taken';
                return response()->json($response, 422);
            }
        }

        $response['email'] = true;

        $subscribes = new Subscribe();
        $subscribes->name = $request->name;
        $subscribes->email = $request->email;
        $subscribes->save();

        return response()->json($response, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though you are returning an error, it is still a response. So move your `$("#response").text(err);` inside `then`

Comment: no it's not working i am retuning respose json 422

Comment: Well, since you are logging the result to console, could you paste here the output from console?

Comment: please check from console  https://ibb.co/BPcRYkD

Answer (score 1):

Add this inside `then` like:

```
axios.post(url, {
                  name: name,
                  email: email,
              })
              .then((res) => {
                  if(res.error){
                     $("#response").text(res.error);
                  }

              })
```

Comment: no it's not working i am returning response json 422

Comment: Please share controller

Comment: please check controller on top

Comment: it has been run from this code thanks to all     catch (err) { 
  console.error(err.response.data.errors);
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$.post('some.php', {name: name, email: email})
    .done(function(msg){  })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        // error handling
    });
```

Another way :

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#prospects_form").submit(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          let url = "{{route('home.store')}}";
          var name = $("#name").val();
          var email = $("#email").val();

          $.ajax({
              url:"",data:"name="+name+"&email="+email,type:"post",dataType:"json"
              success: function(msg){
                 alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
              },
              error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 alert("some error");
              }
          }).done((res) => {
                  console.log(res);
          });
      });
  });
```